# Will using of non CLS compliant types in a language which doesn't support unsigned cause issue?

Tags: .net, c++-cli, unsigned, cls-compliant

My case is:

I'm working a .net library which wraps an existing C++ library. One method in C++ returns an unsigned int and I also want to return the .net corresponding method with an System.Uint32.

Will this cause some issue for languages which don't support unsigned data types?

Answer (score 1):

Most probably there will be issues (especially when you return numbers which are greater than 2^31), but according to this SO post

[Are there languages compatible with .NET that don't support unsigned types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364986/are-there-languages-compatible-with-net-that-dont-support-unsigned-types)

it seems there are not many .NET languages (or, no important ones, though importance may be subjective) which don't support unsigned data types.

Comment: Currently, I don't know which language doesn't support unsigned.

For unsigned data like 2^31, can we consume it like System.Int64 intData = getUnsignedData() ?

Comment: @softempire: I would not expect that working, you will probably get a negative return value (but I cannot verify this since I don't have a .NET language at hand with no unsigned types). But isn't that discussion purely theoretical?

Answer (score 0):

If a class is legitimately CLS compliant, the only features one should require languages to support things beyond the CLS minimum requirements would be those which would be meaningless in the absence of such features.  For example, a CLS-compliant method group may include overloads for unsigned integer types if any functionality provided by those methods would be available via other means.

If a class is supposed to do something like provide a means of reading and writing unsigned 32-bit values from some external data set, CLS compliance would not forbid the type from providing methods that read and write data of type `UInt32`, but would require that any data which could be read or written via such methods must be readable by other methods that do not require that type [e.g. they could use `Int64` instead].  Client code which uses `Int64` might less efficient than would be code using `UInt32`, but the failure of a language to support `UInt32` wouldn't prevent the client code from doing what it needs to do--it would merely slow it down slightly.