# Why is there no Sum() extension for IEnumerable<uint>

Tags: .net

It seems that Sum is not defined for `IEnumerable<uint>` (and other unsigned integers, for that matter)

```
var s = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
s.Sum(); //works fine

var us = new uint[] { 1, 2, 3 };
us.Sum(); //missing method
```

I would like to know:

- Have I done something fundamentally wrong/misunderstood the situation?
- What design decisions might cause the omission of `IEnumerable<uint>.Sum()`?

[MSDN: Enumerable.Sum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sum%28VS.90%29.aspx)

Comment: You could always make one yourself...

Comment: All features start at -100: http://blogs.msdn.com/ericgu/archive/2004/01/12/57985.aspx

Comment: @Trillian Excellent point, but why did the `int` feature overcome the -100 when the `uint` did not?

Comment: @dss539 there were at least 100 devs by Microsoft who needed the sum by `int` somewhere else while developing .NET.

Answer (score 6):

Just a guess: Because uint is not CLS-compliant.  Not sure if that would weigh in their decision to not support it.

Comment: Yep, that would do it.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325/why-are-unsigned-ints-not-cls-compliant)

Answer (score 0):

It might just be an oversight. I'm reminded of [ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx), which is available on Lists but not IEnumerable. I've written .ForEach as an extension method to IEnumerable in at least 3 projects.

Comment: ...Except that `ForEach` was not an oversight.  It was deliberately not included in `IEnumerable` extension methods, since those are meant to be functional, and `ForEach` is fundamentally not functional.  That said, it **should** be an extension method in IList; see [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/552410/move-lots-of-helpful-methods-from-list-to-ilist-using-extension-methods) (and upvote!).