# Why no linq for byte, uint?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Enumerable.Sum() is only defined for IEnumerable where T in

double,
   double?
   int,
   int?
   decimal,
   decimal?
   long,
   long?
   float,
   float?

Is there a reason for not defining for byte, short or uint?

1. Is it to avoid overflow problems?
2. Or does it make type inference difficult for compiler? (Most Likely)

Comment: `uint`is _not_ CLS compliant, so supporting it in LINQ is right out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ aggregate functions on bytes, shorts, and unsigned values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334839/linq-aggregate-functions-on-bytes-shorts-and-unsigned-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when you add a short and a short the outcome can be handled by an int.
Could be some CLS compliant issues as well. This was posted as a similiar question:

[Why is there no Sum() extension for IEnumerable<uint>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784522/why-is-there-no-sum-extension-for-ienumerableuint)

Comment: @akash kava - CLS compliance issues