# Unsigned Interlocked Reads

Tags: c#, multithreading, unsigned, interlocked

What is the reasoning behind Interlocked.Read() only being defined for Int64 and not for UInt64? I wouldn't have thought there was any difference between the two types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Interlocked` class is defined in `mscorlib` which is [CLS-Compliant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhc3fa7f.aspx) and `UInt32` and `UInt64` are, for better or for worse, not CLS-Compliant.

As for why they are not CLS-Compliant, see this SO article:

- [Why are unsigned int's not CLS compliant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325/why-are-unsigned-ints-not-cls-compliant)

Comment: CLS compliance seems a silly reason not to define Interlocked operations for unsigned variables.  The purpose of CLS compliance is to ensure that languages without certain optional features are not excluded from using library functions that would be useful to them if they were defined differently.  A CompareExchange overload which accepts unsigned parameters would be useful to those languages with unsigned types, and useless to those without it, but defining an overload that way would not impair the usefulness of anything that *would otherwise be useful* in such a language.