# C# DWORD and QWORD - signed and unsigned madness

Tags: c#, registry, dword

I've noticed that `DWord` and `QWord` values when written to the Registry supposed to be Signed Integers, not Unsigned. This code will throw an exception if value is UInt64 or UInt32:

```
registryKey.SetValue(name, value);
```

According to MSDN `DWORD` is a 32-bit unsigned integer (range: 0 through 4294967295 decimal) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230318.aspx

So, to write new `DWORD` value to the Registry I need to cast it to signed integer like so:

```
UInt32 unsignedValue = (UInt32)someValue;
Int32 signedValue = (Int32)unsignedValue;
registryKey.SetValue(name, signedValue);
```

Passing unsigned value to **SetValue** method will throw an exception.
Am I missing something or I just being retarded?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For [historical reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325/why-are-unsigned-ints-not-cls-compliant), the .NET API/libraries is normally "signed" instead of being "signed + unsigned".

But in the end, a `signed int` and a `unsigned int` both occupy the same memory space, and there is no special handling done for negative values. So you can do as you said: cast the unsigned value to signed, write it with `SetValue` and then if you look at the value in `Regedit` you'll see that it was written "unsigned".

Note that if your program is compiled in "checked" mode, a more correct code would be:

```
uint unsignedValue = ... // Your original value

int signedValue = unchecked((int)unsignedValue);
registryKey.SetValue(name, signedValue);
```

Because in "checked" mode casting between `int` and `uint` can throw an exception if the conversion isn't possible.

Note that as written [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/2kk9bxk9.aspx):

> This overload of SetValue stores 64-bit integers as strings (RegistryValueKind.String). To store 64-bit numbers as RegistryValueKind.QWord values, use the SetValue(String, Object, RegistryValueKind) overload that specifies RegistryValueKind.

Clearly you'll have to do the same handling for signed-unsigned.

Answer (score 1):

From the [RegistryKey.SetValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/2kk9bxk9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page' example:

```
// Numeric values that cannot be interpreted as DWord (int) values
// are stored as strings.
```

It seems the stored values are signed ints or strings.